# Mysql trigger creation fails with error #1064

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I am trying to create a trigger After_Insert on table ORDERS via phpMyAdmin:

```
DECLARE v1 VARCHAR DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE v2 VARCHAR DEFAULT '0';
IF NEW.PFIELD =0 
THEN 
(
SELECT a.NAME,a.CONTACT INTO v1,v2 FROM ADDRESSBOOK a WHERE a.ID=NEW.ID_SENDER LIMIT 1;
REPLACE INTO _SENDERS (AID,OID,OTP,NAME,CONTACT) VALUES (NEW.ID_SENDER,NEW.ID,NEW.OTYPE,v1,v2);
)
ELSE 
(
SELECT ap.NAME,ap.CONTACT INTO v1,v2 FROM ADDRESSBOOK_P ap WHERE ap.ID=NEW.PFIELD LIMIT 1;
REPLACE INTO _SENDERS_P (AID,OID,OTP,NAME,CONTACT) VALUES (NEW.PFIELD,NEW.ID,NEW.OTYPE,v1,v2);
)
END IF;
```

but i am getting the default MySQL error :

```
MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE v1 VARCHAR DEFAULT NULL; DECLARE v2 VARCHAR DEFAULT NULL; IF NEW....' at line 1
```

What i am doing wrong?
I am an experienced mySQL/php user , but not really friend with the triggers, now i decided to rewrite my hardcoded php code into triggers (where it can be done)

thanks for your suggestions

Comment: Provide COMPLETE trigger text - from CREATE TRIGGER till the final END. Add complete CREATE TABLE for each mentioned table.

Comment: You cannot use SELECT into the output stream in the trigger. You can declare local variables only at the beginning of the BEGIN-END block.

Comment: @Akina  - i am doing it from phpMyAdmin from the browser, i can only modify the body text and select Before/After  + Insert/Update/Delete from listboxes in phpMyAdmin, so the text in my original post is the whole script i wrote

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem solved, honestly don't know where exactly was the problem, but when i wrote into new SQL script the `WHOLE DROP IF EXISTS / CREATE` script, he MySQL server accepted that trigger and it works correctly.

weird..
thanks for the indirect suggestion @Akina

now, my script looks like this:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER _AI_ORDERS_
AFTER INSERT
   ON ORDERS FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

DECLARE v1 VARCHAR DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE v2 VARCHAR DEFAULT '0';
IF NEW.PFIELD =0 
THEN 
(
SELECT a.NAME,a.CONTACT INTO v1,v2 FROM ADDRESSBOOK a WHERE a.ID=NEW.ID_SENDER LIMIT 1;
REPLACE INTO _SENDERS (AID,OID,OTP,NAME,CONTACT) VALUES (NEW.ID_SENDER,NEW.ID,NEW.OTYPE,v1,v2);
)
ELSE 
(
SELECT ap.NAME,ap.CONTACT INTO v1,v2 FROM ADDRESSBOOK_P ap WHERE ap.ID=NEW.PFIELD LIMIT 1;
REPLACE INTO _SENDERS_P (AID,OID,OTP,NAME,CONTACT) VALUES (NEW.PFIELD,NEW.ID,NEW.OTYPE,v1,v2);
)
END IF;

END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: You do not need in intermediate SELECT and both variables. Simply use REPLACE .. SELECT.

Comment: @Akina thanks, i know that, but some of the triggers are more 'wild' and there are 20+ variables, it could make chaos in my scripts, for the future, to have better readable code, however it can cost few extra % of the server resources.